# CMB2 Filelist type paginate results (uses get_post_meta)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

This is getting close to what I need. It splits out 5 results from the $files (get_post_meta) and creates pages but the images are all the same images on all the pages. I am beyond the limit of my brain.

```
function gallery_loop() {

if( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $page = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else {
    $page = 1;
}


$img_size = 'portfolio-catalog';


$files = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true);
$limit = 5;
$total = count( $files );
$pages = ceil( $total / $limit );

$curr_page = isset($_GET['page']);
$offset = ($curr_page - 1) * $limit;


$items_array = array_chunk((array) $files, $limit, true); 

$files_array = array_slice($items_array, $offset, true); // this is showing the same 5 items on all the pages

foreach ($files_array as $files) {

    echo '<div style="border:1px solid red;">'; //BEGIN "page" so I can see if they are splitting correctly

    foreach ($files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url) {

    $page=1;

        echo '<div class="file-list-image">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $img_size);
        echo '</div>';

    $page++;


    } // end $files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url

    echo '</div>'; //END "page" so I can see if they are splitting correctly


} // end foreach $files_array as $files



//the correct amount of pages are showing up but the items are all the same
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => get_permalink() . '%#%' . '/',
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => $page,
    'total' => $pages
  ) );


}
// end function
```

Comment: split the array into chunks using `array_chunk` and then process each chunk as the paginated set of files possibly

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

**PHP**

```
<?php

$files_array=array_chunk((array) $files, 10, true); //10 is an amount per page here
foreach ($files_array as $files)
{
    $page=1;
    echo '<div data-imgpage="' . $page . '" class="images_page' . (($page > 1) ? 'hidden_class' : '') . '">';
    foreach ($files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url)
    {
        echo '<div class="file-list-image">';
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, $img_size);
        echo '</div>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
    $page++;
}

// now create some pagination if needed
echo ((count($files_array) > 1) ? '<div class="pagination_container">' . create_pagination(1, count($files_array)) . '</div>' : '');

function create_pagination($current_page, $limit)
{
    $first=((($current_page - 2) > 0) ? $current_page - 2 : 1);
    $last=((($current_page + 2) < $limit) ? $current_page + 2 : $limit);
    $html='<ul data-imglisting-pagination-max="' . $limit . '">';
    if ($first > 1)
    {
        $html .= '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="1" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"><span class="page_class">1</span></li>';
        $html .= '<li data-imglisting-pagination-action="disabled" class="disabled_page_class"><span>...</span></li>';
    }
    for ($i=$first; $i <= $last; $i ++)
    {
        $html .= '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="' . $i . '" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active" ' . (($current_page == $i) ? 'class="active_page_class"' : "" ) . '><span class="page_class">' . $i . '</span></li>';
    }
    if ($last < $limit)
    {
        $html .= '<li data-imglisting-pagination-action="disabled" class="disabled_page_class"><span>...</span></li>';
        $html .= '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="' . $limit . '" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"><span class="page_class">' . $limit . '</span></li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    return $html;
}
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
    var current_page = 1;
    bind_stuff();
    function bind_stuff()
    {
        $('[data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"]').unbind('click');
        $('[data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"]').click(function ()
        {
            if (current_page != $(this).attr('data-imglisting-pagination-page'))
            {
                current_page = $(this).attr('data-imglisting-pagination-page');
                $('[data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"]').removeClass('active_page_class');
                $('[data-imgpage]').hide();
                $('[data-imgpage="' + current_page + '"]').show();
                $(this).addClass('active_page_class');
                $('.pagination_container').html(build_pagination(current_page, parseInt($('data-imglisting-pagination-max').attr('data-imglisting-pagination-max'))));
                bindStuff();
            }
        });
    }
});
function build_pagination(current, limit)
{
    var first = (((current - 2) > 0) ? current - 2 : 1);
    var last = (((current + 2) < limit) ? current + 2 : limit);
    output = '<ul data-imglisting-pagination-max="' + limit + '">';
    if (first > 1)
    {
        output = output + '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="1" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"><span class="page_class">1</span></li>';
        output = output + '<li data-imglisting-pagination-action="disabled" class="disabled_page_class"><span>...</span></li>';
    }
    for (i = first; i <= last; i++)
    {
        output = output + '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="' + i + '" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active" ' + ((current == i) ? 'class="active_page_class"' : "") + '><span class="page_class">' + i + '</span></li>';
    }
    if (last < limit)
    {
        output = output + '<li data-imglisting-pagination-action="disabled" class="disabled_page_class"><span>...</span></li>';
        output = output + '<li data-imglisting-pagination-page="' + limit + '" data-imglisting-pagination-action="active"><span class="page_class">' + limit + '</span></li>';
    }
    output = output + '</ul>';
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting. You have almost what I need. I don't want js pages, I want real pages. I updated the OP question using your answer plus some other stuff and it's very close, the page numbers are correct, but the images on those pages are all the same because of some issue (that I can't figure out) with the $files_array, I tried adding the $offset to yours and it was beyond the amount of parameters allowed. If you have the time, take a look again.

Comment: @Christina edited it according to your needs. This should work, if it doesn't, show me an example value of `$files=get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true);`

Comment: It doesn't work, but I figured out another way using the built in archive in Wordpress for their media library. The original answer answered the question even if it used JS, so if you put that back, I will award the points (takes a couple days due to StackOverflow's guidlines).

Comment: @Christina done. Though, can you give me some sample value of that field? Just wanna get it to work out of curiosity :P

Comment: The `$files = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_cmb_gallery_images', true);` is referred to as a file_list type of field which has many images, then to get each image individually, they use `$files as $attachment_id => $attachment_url ` which is each individual image. That was one of the issues. CMB2 is the library that works with WordPress that allows a developer to make custom metaboxes (fields) that appear (like a file_list) that I can just drag my images into and display, but there's no pagination.

Comment: @Christina any chance you can give me an example of how it's actually stored in db?

Comment: To answer that is way beyond my skill set. I looked in phpMyadmin and there's a ton of posts (every iteration) and I will assume that an image is a post type called attachment, since it has arguments just like a regular article or blog post, but how it's stored in the DB -- I couldn't find the images but there's tons of pages and I changed the rows to show 250 and it still went on and on. Sorry.

Comment: There's another premium plugin called Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and it has a gallery field which you can paginate since they check for rows, however I discovered that by using taxonomies on the images in the library, I could call the posts (in this case images) by category and use the builtin pagination.